# PHP cannot assign query result to variable

Tags: php

I am trying to use Sendgrid to send an email which shows information from a database.

my code:

```
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "
<?php foreach ($dueinsevendays as $dueinsevenday) :

$sevendaycomref = $dueinsevenday['ceref'];
$sevendaytitle = $dueinsevenday['cetitle'];
$sevendaydate = $dueinsevenday['targetresponse'];
$sevendaystage = $dueinsevenday['cestage'];

?>
<tr>        
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaycomref</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaytitle</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaydate</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaystage</td>   
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
")
```

i am getting an error with assigning query results to variables for example where it says "$dueinsevenday['ceref'];", the first [ shows as an error (syntax error, unexpected quoted-string and whitespace).

i need to create a table row for each record in the database that is returned from the query, if i assign the variables outside of this php code there are no errors but the loop does not work, this code will only show one table row instead of all e.g:

```
$sevendaycomref = $dueinsevenday['ceref'];
$sevendaytitle = $dueinsevenday['cetitle'];
$sevendaydate = $dueinsevenday['targetresponse'];
$sevendaystage = $dueinsevenday['cestage'];

$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "
<?php foreach ($dueinsevendays as $dueinsevenday) :


?>
<tr>        
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaycomref</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaytitle</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaydate</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaystage</td>   
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
")
```

Any ideas on how to either fix the error or rearrange the code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First run the loop aur what ever the code is and then assign the response value to the variable.

Comment: See the highlighting in the post? That means your syntax is not what you think it is, so the php code is not being run.

Comment: You can't write PHP in a string. If the string is double quoted, you can use variables in it, but not code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be placing PHP code inside a string variable and expecting it to be executed as code. It won't, it'll be treated as if it was the intended content of the email. You need to process the data first, add the necessary HTML into a string variable, and then add that string - i.e. the *result* of your code, not the code itself - to the email.

Try it like this:

```
$html = "";
foreach ($dueinsevendays as $dueinsevenday)
{
  $html .= "<tr>        
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$sevendaycomref</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$dueinsevenday['cetitle']</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$dueinsevenday['targetresponse']</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>$dueinsevenday['cestage']</td>   
    </tr>";
} 
$email->addContent("text/html", $html);
```